# Using website specific php.ini file

Tags: iis, web-hosting, php

I have a website running on shared IIS server. The hosting service provider is not making changes to the file. I need to set **`display_errors`** to **`off`**. I asked them for the php.ini file from their server to be mailed to me. Can I override the default ini file to the php.ini file in my root directory?

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution. I used `error_reporting(0);` to turn off displaying errors. This might help others looking for same solution.